# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

```
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import os.path
import scipy as sp
import sys
def dist_raw(v1,v2):
    delta=v1-v2
    return sp.linalg.norm(delta.toarray())#метод норм вовзращает евклидово число

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=1)
posts=[open(os.path.join("D:\DIR",f)).read() for f in os.listdir("D:\DIR")]
X_train=vectorizer.fit_transform(posts)
num_samples,num_features=X_train.shape
print("<<samples:%d, features:%d>>" % (num_samples,num_features))
new_post="imaging databases"
new_post_vec = vectorizer.transform([new_post])
print(new_post_vec)
print(new_post_vec.toarray())
best_doc = None
best_dist = sys.maxsize
best_i=None
for i,post in enumerate(num_samples):
    if post == new_post:
        continue
    post_vec=X_train.getrow(i)`введите сюда код`
    d= dist_raw(post_vec,new_post_vec)
    print("=== Post %i with dist = %.2f: %s"%(i,d,post))
    if d<best_dist:
        best_dist = d
        best_i = i
    print("Best post is %i with dist=%.2f"%(best_i,best_dist))
```

Делаю пример по книге и получаю такую ошибку

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Из-за чего появляется ошибка?

Comment: добавьте полный стек ошибки или хотя бы укажите какая строка кода вызывает ошибку...

Comment: строка:
    for i,post in enumerate(num_samples):

Comment: `num_samples` - целое число, `enumerate()` ожидает объект по которому можно итерировать (list, set, dict, etc,)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подозреваю, что должно быть так:

```
for i, post in enumerate(posts):
```